# Code First Migration deletes all data

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code First Migrations in my Web API (Mobile Service .NET backend) and whenever my model changes, all data is deleted from my database. This is what I am doing:

1. I add a new property to my model
2. I run "Add-Migration AddTestProperty" in the Package Manager console
3. The new migration is added to the Migrations folder (see code below)

   ```
   public partial class AddTestProperty: DbMigration
   {
   public override void Up()
   {
       AddColumn("testdb.TestTable", "Test", c => c.String());
   }

   public override void Down()
   {
       DropColumn("testdb.TestTable", "Test");
   }
   }
   ```

My configuration looks like this:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }
```

Now if I run my webservice, the property is added to my TestTable but all data in all my tables is deleted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason my data was deleted from my database is this: If you use the service project downloaded from the Azure portal, you will find the following code in the App_Start/WebsApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
        ConfigOptions options = new ConfigOptions();

        // Use this class to set WebAPI configuration options
        HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));

        Database.SetInitializer(new todoInitializer());
    }
}

public class todoInitializer : ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges<todoContext>
{
    .....
```

To enable Code First Migrations on a Mobile Services .NET backend you need to replace the Database.SetInitializer(new todoInitializer()); with this:

```
    //Database.SetInitializer(new todoInitializer());
    var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
    migrator.Update();
```

This requires the following using statements:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using todoService.Migrations;
```

More information on [how to enable Code First Migrations on a Mobile Service .NET backend](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/03/28/mobile-services-net-backend-initializers-and-model-updates.aspx).